# What language is most similar to Basque?

Tags: comparative-linguistics, language-isolates, basque

While Basque remains firmly a language isolate and AFAIK it's origins (along with that of the Basque people) remain shrouded in mystery, I wonder if there are any languages, living or dead, that actually have resemblance to Basque in terms of phonetics but also grammar.

Comment: Georgian has no gender, but has ergative patterns in some tenses

Comment: @ColinFine out of curiosity does Georgian distinguish between animate and inanimate? I do remember reading theories about Georgians and Basques being related but in addition to no linguistic evidence, there is no genetic relationship between these 2 peoples.

Comment: There are >100 Pama-Nyungan languages (Australia) that are ergative and have no grammatical gender.

Comment: I assume you are referring to structural similarity, such as "has suffixes not prefixes", and not substantive similarity like "has a suffix -ban".

Comment: In terms of phonetics, Basque is quite unexceptional: the five basic vowels /a e i o u/; voiced and unvoiced labial, denti-alveolar, palatal/postalveolar and velar plosives; the most common liquids /l ɾ r/; some common sibilants and fricatives; lenition of intervocalic voiced plosives to fricatives/approximants, etc. The only thing that’s unusual phonetically is the distinction between laminal and apical sibilants and affricates (but not plosives or liquids) – though that is _very_ unusual. Aside from some Spanish dialects, I’m not aware of any other languages that have this distinction.

Comment: (Apical/laminal distinctions are not very rare as such – they’re especially common in Indian and Australian languages – but they tend to apply to plosives and sometimes laterals. To only have a laminal/apical distinction in sibilants and sibilant affricates is very unusual.)

Comment: Not that I remeber, @MrX (though I never got very far into Georgian) The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georgian_grammar) doesn't mention the word "animate" or "animacy".

Comment: If you're curious about Basque and its origins, read Randy Trask's _Historical Linguistics_. Trask was a Vasconist and many of the examples showing language change and development are from Basque.

Comment: @MrX - Georgian distinguishes between animate and inanimate on the lexical level: some actions are expressed with different verbs depending on the animacy of their objects, e.g. the verb ‘to have’ is ჰყავს (hq̇avs) when used to signify a possession of animate objects (human or animal) or cars, whereas აქვს (akvs) is left for inanimate objects (except for cars). With prefixes other verbs are formed from these two verbs, thus there're 2 verbs ‘to bring, to take’, მიჰყავს (mihq̇avs) and მიაქვს (miakvs), the choice depending on _who_ or _what_ is taken to a place.